# Spring 5 - How to get path variables from ServerHttpRequest object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Hi I would like to get a path variable from the ServerHttpRequest object - what's the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: [Reference](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=making/spring-boot-actuator-dashboard/spring-boot-actuator-dashboard-master/src/main/java/am/ik/spring/actuator/proxy/ProxyController.java) , check for `PathContainer wildcard = request.getPath().subPath(5);` which gives a good example